# Check and uncheck checkbox with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked, unchecked

Very basic question here, I am using a [JS library](https://github.com/rickellis/shortcuts) to add keyboard shortcuts, I want to check and uncheck a checkbox using the same line of commands, but I am not sure about how to do this, here is the code:

```
shortcuts.add('alt+s', function() {
        document.getElementById("menu-toggle").checked = true 
    })
```

How can I use the same shortcut to uncheck the same element?

```
        document.getElementById("menu-toggle").checked = false;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get the element, and if its checked property is true, set it to false and if it's false, set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `Element.toggleAttribute`:

```js
const toggleChecked = () => document.getElementById('menu-toggle').toggleAttribute('checked');
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', toggleChecked);
```

```html
<input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox"> Check me
<br><br>
<button id="myBtn">Click me</button>
```